# Why doesn't my Beast Whistle work?

Tags: final-fantasy-15

Often when I'm waiting for day to change to night, I try to call enemies using the Beast Whistle to pass the time.

[image: Beast Whistle]

However recently, I've tried it in lots of different places and it doesn't seem to actually call any enemies.

Are there certain criteria I need to meet, such as being a wide open space, before enemies will spawn?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The beast whistle typically works best where mods typically spawn, and it's helpful to not look at the spawn point (just like calling a Chocobo). Still, the beast whistle isn't an item that guarantees you'll strike fire with every use but instead offers the ability to attract beasts (the item description could've been more accurate, I believe.)

Additionally, time of day and normally spawned monsters impact which beasts are called.

As of right now, I am unable to find a static list of specific criteria and the above are personal observations when I had the same question after obtaining the whistle.

Comment: Turns out you need a pretty decent clear area, which is flat, and has no trees. I tried near the Vesperpool with no luck, tried near Alstor Slough and it worked first time.